# How can we use two types of UICollectionViewCell for a single UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have two types of UICollectionViewCell : one is gallery cell and another is recipe cell.

There is a toggle button.
First time the view loads, gallery cell is used to display in collection view.

But on clicking the toggle button, I tried to load another cell:(recipe cell) but it crashed saying there is no property(actually this is the property of recipe cell) in gallery cell.

Is there a way to load same collection view with another cell??

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

```
    if (isGalleryOnCollectionView) {

    ProfileFollowerCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"  forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *followerName;

    if ([[arr_followerNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@""]) {
        followerName=[arr_followersEmail objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else{
        followerName=[arr_followerNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    NSLog(@"\n\n\n follower name is :: %@\n\n",followerName);

    cell.lbl_followerName.text = followerName;

}else{

        GalleryCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


        cell.lbl_recipeName.text = [[[dict_profileData valueForKey:@"recipes"] valueForKey:@"name"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


}
```

SOLUTION:

```
[self.profleCollectionView registerClass:[ProfileFollowerCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"followercell"];
```

After registering from the nib before dequeuing reusable identifier it works.

Comment: Post code that `- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is returning

Comment: @random,  if i load one type of cell  say ProfileFollowerCell in collection view  and if I reload collectionview and try to use next cell it crashes( it is using old cell )

Comment: I tried to make the collectionview nil before reloading but doesn't works

Comment: Use a different `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` and see if that works

Comment: Nice suggestion, but throws this following exception:Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier followercell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Comment: Are you creating your cells with `xib`s

Comment: yes and i'm searching to register cell from code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here is a good tutorial on creating custom `UICollectionViewCell` with xibs.](http://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2012/09/a-simple-uicollectionview-tutorial/)

What your missing is having this in your `-(void)viewDidLoad`

```
UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"ProfileFollowerCellNib" bundle:nil];
[self.collectionView registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"TheNibCellIdentifier"];
```

You also need to make sure to use the respective `ReuseIdentifier` when loading the cell:

```
ProfileFollowerCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"TheNibCellIdentifier"  forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: I also figured that out but anyway thanks, and also thanks for  pointing my reuse identifier.